# Multiple WHERE clause for same Columns in TSQL

Tags: t-sql, entity-framework-4

I am trying to query two tables that are in 1-to-many relationship. 
What I've done is create a View knowing that i might end up with multiple records for the first table.

My scenario is as follows: I have a table "Items" and table "Properties".

"Properties" table contains an ItemsId column, PropertyId, PropertyValueId columns.

"Items" table/object contains a list of "Properties".

How would I query that "View" such that, I want to get all "Items" records that have a combination of "PropertyId" & "PropertyValueId" values.

In other words something similar to:

```
WHERE
 (PropertyId = @val1 AND PropertyValueId = @val2) OR
 (PropertyId = @val3 AND PropertyValueId = @val4) OR
 (PropertyId = @val5 AND PropertyValueId = @val6)
```

WHERE clause is just a loop over "Items.Properties" collection.

"Items" represents a table of Items being stored in the database. Each & every Item has some dynamic properties, one or more. That's why I have another table called "Properties". Properties table contains columns:
ItemId, PropertyId, PropertyValue

"Item" object has a collection of Properties/Values. Prop1:val1, Prop2:val2, etc ...

Thanks

Comment: If they are both tables can't you just join using two columns? Can you be clear about what the Items table looks like and where val1, val2 etc are coming from?

Comment: I see people answering in SQL, but I assume you're looking for a linq query? Otherwise I don't understand the entity-framework tag.

Answer (score 0):

I may not have understood your requirement (despite the update) - if this or any other answer doesn't solve the problem please add some sample data for Items, Properties and the output and then hopefully it would become clear.

If Items is a specification of the property name-value pairs that you need (and has nothing to do with ItemId on Properties which seems strange...)

```
select p.itemid  
from properties p  
where exists (select 1 from items i where i.propertyId = p.propertyId and i.propertyValueId = p.propertyValueId)  
group by p.itemid  
having count(distinct p.propertyid) = (select count(*) from items)
```

This returns a set of itemids that have one (and only one) property value for each property defined in items. You can put the items count into a variable if you want.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a query like this:

```
SELECT ItemId
FROM ItemView
WHERE (PropertyId = @val1 AND PropertyValueId = @val2)
   OR (PropertyId = @val3 AND PropertyValueId = @val4)
   OR (PropertyId = @val5 AND PropertyValueId = @val6)
GROUP BY ItemId
HAVING COUNT(*) = 3
```

The `WHERE` clause is the same as in your question, it only allows a row to be selected if the row has a matching property. You only need to make sure additionally that the items obtained have *all* the properties in the filter, which is done in the above query with the help of the `HAVING` clause: you are requesting items with 3 specific properties, therefore the number of properties per item in your result set (`COUNT(*)`) should be equal to 3.

In a more general case, when the number of properties queried may be arbitrary, you should probably consider passing the arguments in the form of a table and join the view to it:

```
…
FROM ItemView v
  INNER JOIN RequestedProperties r ON v.PropertyId      = r.Id
                                  AND v.PropertyValueId = r.ValueId
GROUP BY v.ItemId
HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM RequestedProperties)
```

Comment: Pass Tables as parameter to Query?

Comment: As an option, yes, if you are using SQL Server 2008+, which supports table-valued parameters. An alternative might be to pass the list as a CSV string, split it with a function into rows and then, possibly, split each item into two columns (property id and property value id). Or maybe you could prepare beforehand a temporary table containing the required properties, and use that table in your query. (Thus you would be passing the parameters implicitly, which may or may not be a good idea, depending on your situation.)